# Passing Subprotocols in Robot Framework's websocketclient Library

Tags: python, websocket, robotframework

I am trying to connect with a websocket client using robot framework by using the following code:

`Library  WebSocketClient
 ${my_websocket}=  WebSocketClient.Connect  ws://<url>/1029922`

But, this request is incomplete because i also need to setup a subprotocol for same, so changed the request to:

`${my_websocket}=  WebSocketClient.Connect  ws://<url>/1029922  subprotocols=ocpp1.6`

As per https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/master/websocket/_core.py, to setup a subprotocol we need to pass this parameters as options, and this will accept "array of available sub protocols" but when my request is processed,  the protocol is passed as "[o,c,
p,p,1,.,6]

Please help what I need to correct and how to pass the request with subprotocol.

Comment: Have you tried to pass it as a list of one item?

Comment: Yes, i did.. i also checked the library file _core.py from websocket directory, the code is something like: `headers.append("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: %s" % ",".join(subprotocols))`